# How to set date in this page using AngularJS

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've this [page](https://www.irctc.co.in/nget/train-search) in  my autofill using JQuery how do I set the date ? For example "29-06-2018".

```
 $("p-calendar input").focus();
    document.execCommand('selectAll');
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, "29-06-2018");
```

does not work. It seems it does set to this but it automatically reverts to today's date.

Can I include AngularJS library and then change it easily?

Comment: @wOxxOm i've updated the question

Comment: Sounds like their script runs after yours. Try setTimeout or run yours from `load` event on `window` object.